# help using pcap library to sniff packets

Tags: c, pcap, sniffer

i am using pcap sample codes to create my own sniffer. i downloaded their sample sniffer and its working on windows but not on linux. i am using gcc compiler on both machines, and i have only pcap.h included.
the error is : dereferencing pointer to incomplete type.
the netmask is causing the error. the netmask is the mask of the first address of the interface.

```
u_int netmask=netmask((struct sockaddr_in*)d->addresses->netmask))->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;
```

any solutions?

Comment: http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/ might also interest you.

Comment: structsockaddr_in -- Aren't you missing a space between struct and sockaddr_in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler indicating that it doesn't have the definition of `struct sockaddr_in` in scope, so it can't look inside such a structure.  On Linux that struct is defined in this header, which you will need to include:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
```